# How to resolve typescript error "Not all code paths return a value." in function in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
interface ITimer {
  minutes: number,
  seconds: number,
  completed: boolean
};

const renderTimer = ({ minutes, seconds, completed }: ITimer)  => {
  if (completed) {
    console.log('time is up')
  } else {
  return <em>{minutes}:{seconds}</em>
  }
};
```

after I set the type of minutes, seconds and completed argument in renderTimer function, I get a yellow line error under **({ minutes, seconds, completed }: ITimer)  => {**  saying

```
var completed: boolean
Not all code paths return a value.
```

this error occurs because the function does not return the value of **completed**.

How can I tell this function that **minutes** and **seconds** are only returned value using typescript?

Comment: no, this warning occurs, because your function only returns something in the `else` case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something on `if` condition.

```js
interface ITimer {
  minutes: number,
  seconds: number,
  completed: boolean
};

const renderTimer = ({ minutes, seconds, completed }: ITimer)  => {
  if (completed) {
    console.log('time is up')
    return null; //or <></>
  } else {
  return <em>{minutes}:{seconds}</em>
  }
};
```